# BVN404 gadget showing in local dev, but not EpiServer integration enviornment

Tags: episerver, optimizely

I am able to access this gadget in my local dev environment, but not integration, as you can see below:

Local dev:

[image]

Integration:

[image]

I double checked the BVN settings from here: https://github.com/Geta/404handler#configuration. They are setup like this in my web.config:

```
<section name="bvn404Handler" type="BVNetwork.NotFound.Configuration.Bvn404HandlerConfiguration, BVNetwork.EPi404" />

<episerver.shell>
    <publicModules rootPath="~/modules/" autoDiscovery="Modules" />
    <protectedModules rootPath="~/EPiServer/">
        <add name="BVNetwork.404Handler" />

<bvn404Handler handlerMode="On">
    <providers>
        <add name="Custom Handler" type="CompanyName.Business.CustomPageNotFoundHandler, companyname-cms" />
    </providers>
</bvn404Handler>
```

There is not a `securedComponents` section, though I did try to add one with `allowedRoles="Administrator"`, `allowedRoles="*"`, and `allowedRoles="Everyone"` for testing purposes.

Any ideas why the gadget can't be viewed when published?

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that the BVN zip file did not publish to the modules folder for some reason. After adding it back, it worked as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nuget installations sometimes misses the protectedmodules section

Ensure the `BVNetwork.404Handler` is in your protectedModules collection in web.config. Nuget sometimes miss that.

```
<episerver.shell>
    <protectedModules rootPath="~/EPiServer/"> <!-- this line may vary -->
        <!-- other modules -->
        <add name="BVNetwork.404Handler" />
    </protectedModules>
</episerver.shell>
```

Comment: Yeah, I have that. It's the last line of the second XML piece I included with my post.